# Add classes to tag helpers html elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

First time diving into tag helpers but i couldn't understand from tutorials how am i supposed to define the classes for each element?

```
    [HtmlTargetElement("card")]
public class CardTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {

        output.TagName = "CardTagHelper";
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat($@"
                    <div class='card custom-card'>
                        <div class='card-header'>
                            <div class='card-title'>
                                <i class='{Icon}'></i>
                                {Title}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='card-body'>

                        </div>
                        <div class='card-footer'>
                        </div>
                    </div>");

        output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent(sb.ToString());

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "card-body");
    }
}
```

none of these work, it still renders  on page

**EDIT**

What i would like is that the content would be rendered as something like this

```
<card title="title" icon="icon">
 // content
</card>
```

I'm not sure if this is the way to do this or i have to create tag helpers for the card head body and footer

like

```
<card>
    <card-header>
    </card-header>
    <card-body>
    </card-body>
    <card-footer>
    </card-footer>
</card>
```

on view import i injected helper with

```
@addTagHelper *, CardTagHelper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is here:

> ```
> @addTagHelper *, CardTagHelper
> ```

This directive attempts to register all tag-helpers found in a `CardTagHelper` assembly, which doesn't exist. Your tag-helper isn't being found and so isn't being run, leaving the HTML you've added to your .cshtml files completely untouched.

You need to use the name of the assembly that *contains* `CardTagHelper`:

```
@addTagHelper *, YourFullAssemblyName
```